# Angular2- append variable is undefined

Tags: typescript, angular

I am trying to create an own infoWindow which I appen to the parent of a google maps class the function look like this which gets triggered by clicking an marker:

```
updateDiv(location: Location) {
this.selectedLocation = location;
this.isClicked = true;
this.ID = this.selectedLocation.id;


console.log(this.ID)

$(function() {
   $('.gm-style-iw').parent().append('<div class="test"><span class="ID">'+ this.ID +'</span></div>');
 });
}
```

The `console.log` is showing the ID of the clicked marker, but in the `div class='test'` it shows up as undefined.

Why is that?

Or is it also possible to append a div which you created in the html template? Which looks like this:

```
<div *ngIf="isClicked" class="infoWindow">
   <p>{{ selectedLocation.id }} {{ selectedLocation.content }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`function()` orphans `this`:

```
$(function() {
   $('.gm-style-iw').parent().append('<div class="test"><span class="ID">'+ this.ID +'</span></div>');
 });
}
```

to keep the scope of `this` use instead

```
$(() => {
   $('.gm-style-iw').parent().append('<div class="test"><span class="ID">'+ this.ID +'</span></div>');
 });
}
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 1):

Two things.

First: As mentioned by Gunter, you're getting undefined due to the scope. Using fat arrow functions could solve your problem.

Second:
I think a better solution for you problem would be using innerHtml.

```html
<div [innerHtml]="myHtml"></div>
```

And

```js
myHtml: string;


constructor() {
  this.myHtml = '<input type="text">'
}
```

Update! 
As OP is already using the angular-maps component, the best solution is already there with the [SebmGoogleMapInfoWindow](https://angular-maps.com/docs/api/latest/ts/core/SebmGoogleMapInfoWindow-directive.html%22SebmGoogleMapInfoWindow%22)

Inside the component markup you can include your own html:

```html
<sebm-google-map-info-window>
  <div [innerHtml]="infoW" ></div>
</sebm-google-map-info-window>
```

And as the component provides a clickedMarker event. You can use it to insert your custom HTML:

```js
clickedMarker(label: string, index: number) {
    this.infoW = '<input type="text" value="' + label  + '"> <hr> <button class="btn btn-success">Index = ' + index +  '</button>'      
  }
```

Full example Here http://plnkr.co/edit/mG5cXP?p=preview

Comment: This is not working this is what I did: 

` $('.gm-style-iw').parent().append('<div class="test">'+
                                            '<div [innerHtml]="myHtml"></div>'+
                                          '</div>')`

And this one in the constructor but it does not shows the content of the innerHtml

`this.myHtml = '<div class="test">'+
            '<span class="content">'+
              '<span class="ID">'+ this.ID + '</span>'+
              '<span class="content-infowindow">' + this.content + '</span>'+
            '</span></div>'`

Comment: You don't need jQuery at all. The [innerHtml]="myHtml" has to be put inside your template html. 
Think of it as a host for some html code provided by the any variable inside the model.

Comment: But I am appending it to a google-maps class it overlays the standard infoWindow: https://plnkr.co/edit/QZLs74?p=preview

Comment: Oh I missed that. I see you're using the angular-maps component. Did you see that there is a specific component for infoWindow? 
https://angular-maps.com/docs/api/latest/ts/core/SebmGoogleMapInfoWindow-directive.html

I say that, because I'd avoid at all costs using jQuery.

Comment: Yes i am aware of that but I did not found a way to style it yet:(

Comment: Have you tried this:

<sebm-google-map-info-window>
          <div [innerHtml]="myHtml" ></div>
</sebm-google-map-info-window>

I tested it here and it works.

Comment: It's the same approach we tried before. We're just placing the [innerHtml] inside the <sebm-google-map-info-window>.

And inside clickedMarker() function you provide the desired html.

Comment: Yes it is nice but look at my plunker you see that the div is styled in a red infowindow. Thats not possible yet with <sebm-google-map-info-window>